# Leading Underscores in Linux Kernel Programming

Tags: c, linux, naming-conventions

The general use of prefixing with an underscore "_" is to indicate that the instance is an internal functionality that is not usually (or should not be) used directly. In C, this is also used to prevent naming conflicts in the global scope.

However, my question is what determines the number of used underscores? For example, in the Linux kernel, we can see instances of ['_tmp' (one underscore)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/md/md.c#L378), ['__cacheline_aligned' (two underscores)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cache.h#L53), and ['____cacheline_aligned' (four underscores)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cache.h#L41).

One thought I have is that, for example, if a long internal function (prefixed with an underscore) uses another function internally, the latter will be prefixed with two underscores.

Comment: You mean *leading* underscores, of course.  Underscores appearing elsewhere in identifiers have no implications such as those you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. Yes, leading underscores!

Comment: Could it be that the Linux kernal, to quote a term used by the Linux kernal coding style  naming chapter, is _brain-damaged_? Or could it possibly be that a document using such terms is so far from professional, that in practice there are no rules at all for that code base, resulting in some of the worst written C source anyone has ever seen?

Comment: @Lundin honestly Linux kernel source looks perfect in comparison to any GNU code base :')

Answer (score 5):

Identifiers starting with a double underscore are *reserved* by the C programming language specification. This means, it is *illegal* to define your own identifiers starting with a double underscore. (The same applies to identifiers starting with a single underscore followed by a capital letter.)

So, technically, this means that the source code of the Linux kernel is not standards-compliant C code.

However, the Linux kernel is very low-level code and it can only be compiled with specific versions of a small number of C compilers, therefore, the Linux kernel developers know exactly which `__foo` identifiers are used by the compiler and which they can use themselves.

So, the Linux kernel uses identifiers starting with double underscore for the same reason that the C standard forbids them: to make sure, there can be no conflicts with user-defined identifiers.

For example, some Linux kernel header files end up being included in the low-level system libraries (GNU libc, musl, dietlibc, etc.), and using identifiers that are explicitly reserved guarantees that this will not lead to conflicts.

Comment: The low-level system libraries also use reserved identifiers beginning with two underscores, so there are potential conflicts that the Linux kernel and low-level system libraries have to negotiate between themselves, but they should not conflict with user code identifiers if user code follows the rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jörg W Mittag. However, this does not answer my original question, which is what determines the number of underscores used? Why do Linux Kernel programmers sometimes use one underscore, two underscores, and four underscores for example? Is there a specific coding convention about this?

Answer (score 2):

My guess to this problem is the lack of specification.

I've searched the linux documentation and I didn't find anything that says how many leading underscores should a developer use, so the developers used their personal preference.